# How to make bash substitution $(<"filename") silent

Tags: bash, command-substitution, stderr

I want to replace cat:

```
var=$(cat "filename" 2>/dev/null)
```

by bashism syntax:

```
var=$(<"filename")
```

The problem is that I don't know how to make the bashism silent to avoid such warnings:

```
bash: filename: No such file or directory
```

I've tried this:

```
var=$(2>/dev/null <"filename")
```

but it does not read existing files into `var` anymore.

Comment: Technically, [`$(<file)` is a kshism, with the bash implementation being a suboptimal approximation](/a/368663).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrapping the assignment into a compound block and using a redirection on that seems to work:

```
{ var=$(<"$file"); } 2>/dev/null;
```

e.g.

```
$ echo hello > test1; rm -f test2
$ file=test1; { var=$(<"$file"); } 2>/dev/null; echo "${var:-[it is empty]}"
hello
$ file=test2; { var=$(<"$file"); } 2>/dev/null; echo "${var:-"[it is empty]"}"
[it is empty]
```

Just don't use `( .. )` to create a subshell, since then the assigned variable would be lost.

Comment: Thanks! I always forget that *group command* exists beside *subshell*.

Answer (score 3):

Test first to make sure it's available and readable:

```
if [ -f "filename" ] && [ -r "filename" ]; then
    var=$(<"filename")
fi
```

The `-f` test tests whether `filename` refers to a *regular file* and the `-r` test tests whether it's readable by you.

Comment: I don’t think `-f` is really necessary... This still suffers from TOCTTOU but I doubt there’s anything better, short of using `zsh` (which handles `2> /dev/null` here).

Comment: @StephenKitt Well, `-r` will still return true for a directory...

Comment: Ah, yes, I can see that causing problems ;-). Perhaps `! -d` would be better then; POSIX `test -f` excludes a few things it can be useful to redirect from (unlike BSD `test -f` which apparently means “exists and is not a directory”).

Comment: This would be a race condition, so that there might be still ugly output "sometimes". The files I read are maintained outside of my actual script. I just want to read and handle errors afterwards if any. But I really wonder that this extra "non-cat-bashism" seems to by less flexible than `cat`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to first check if the file was exist then read it into variable.

```
[ -e filename ] && var=$(<filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

For reference:

in `zsh`, you can use the `$mapfile` special associative array that maps to the content of the file named as the key (note that it's not related to and predates `bash`'s `mapfile` builtin (which doesn't map files) by a decade or so). It uses `mmap()` so can only be used on regular files.

```
zmodload zsh/mapfile
var=$mapfile[filename]
```

It doesn't output anything if the file cannot be opened or mmaped. To check for errors, you can use the `$ERRNO` special variable:

```
ERRNO=0
var=$mapfile[filename]
if ((ERRNO)); then
  : the mapping failed
fi
```

`$ERRNO` values can be translated to `ENOENT`, `EACCESS`... codes with the `$errnos` array in the `zsh/system` module, or to error strings with the `syserror` builtin in `zsh/system` as well.

You can also do `mapfile[filename]=$var` to change the content of the file, it is a true mapping.

Note that while `$(<filename)` would strip *all* trailing newline characters from the content of `filename`, `$mapfile[filename]` expands to the whole content of the file (including binary files) as-is.